# How can i format a string with 10 digits and 2 letters to yyyyMMddHHmm and then to format it to another string?

Tags: c#, .net

```
myl.Add(AllNews[i].original_time);
```

myl is a List type string and also original_time is a string.

For example now original_time contain the string: `"D140707T2149"`
And now I want to convert this string to be with only numbers without the D and T and to format: `yyyyMMddHHmm` without seconds.

And then in the end to build a string like this:

```
string results = myTime.ToString("hh:mm דווח במקור בתאריך : dd.MM.yy : שעה");
```

The hebrew words stay the same only yhe date and time iwll change each time.

This is what i tried to do:

```
IFormatProvider provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime myTime = DateTime.ParseExact(AllNews[i].original_time, "DyyMMddThhmm", provider);
string results = myTime.ToString("hh:mm דווח במקור בתאריך : dd.MM.yy : שעה");
```

But I'm getting exception on the line:

```
DateTime myTime = DateTime.ParseExact(AllNews[i].original_time, "DyyMMddThhmm", provider);
```

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Then I tried first to remove the `D` and `T` from the string:

```
AllNews[i].original_time = Regex.Replace(AllNews[i].original_time, "[^0-9]", ""); 
IFormatProvider provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime myTime = DateTime.ParseExact(AllNews[i].original_time, "yyyyMMddHHmm", provider);
string results = myTime.ToString("hh:mm דווח במקור בתאריך : dd.MM.yy : שעה");
```

But again same exception as before:

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
       at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
       at ScrollLabelTest.ListsExtractions.listtostringlist(List`1 lnl, List`1 myl) in ListsExtractions.cs:line 345
       at ScrollLabelTest.ListsExtractions.Ext(String filename) in 
ListsExtractions.cs:line 220
       at ScrollLabelTest.Form1..ctor() in Form1.cs:line 127
       at ScrollLabelTest.Program.Main() in Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: The value is this: "1407072149" if i click on the magnifier glass but if i just use a breakpoint and put the mouse on it i see: "D140707T2149" in the original this property is built with D and T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need uppercase `HH` for the hours since you are using a 24h clock(`21`) in:

```
string original_time = "D140707T2149";
```

So this works:

```
DateTime myTime = DateTime.ParseExact(original_time, "DyyMMddTHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#HH_Specifier

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your `D` and `T` with *literal string delimiter* as `'` or ".

Also you need to use [`HH` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#HH_Specifier) instead of [`hh` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hhSpecifier) because your hour is *24-hour clock*.

```
DateTime myTime = DateTime.ParseExact("D140707T2149" ,
                                      "'D'yyMMdd'T'HHmm",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(myTime);
```

Here a <kbd>[**`demonstration`**](http://ideone.com/j3hbRa)</kbd>.

`hh` specifier is for `01` to `12` (*12-hour clock*), `HH` specifier is for `00` to `23`.